# PHP - JPEG Image to RGB value Array Count

Tags: php, html, jpeg, rgb

I am wanting to get an array of RGB values from an image and count the data inside the array. E.g. (2 X 2 pix example.)

```
[[[R, G, B], [R, G, B]], [[R, G, B], [R, G, B]]]
Data = 12
SUM = total from all of the RGB values
```

The code I have now:

```
    <?php
    // open an image
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg'); // imagecreatefromjpeg/png/
    // get image dimension, define colour array
    $width = imagesx($image);
    $height = imagesy($image);
    $colors = [];
    for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++)
    {
        for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++)
        {
            $rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
            $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
            $y_array=array($r,$g,$b);
            $x_array[]=$y_array;
        }
        $colors=$x_array;
    }
    print_r($colors);
    print_r(sizeof($colors));
    print_r(array_sum($colors));
    ?>
```

Output that i get :

```
[[[0, 255, 0], [255, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 255], [255, 255, 255]]]
    Data = 2
    SUM = 0
```

The above is not working. My image is now just a 2 X 2 pix jpeg which should output:

```
[[[0, 255, 0], [255, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 255], [255, 255, 255]]]
Data = 12
SUM = 0+255+0+255+0+0+0+0+255+255+255+255 = 2295
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here seems to be the fact that you are not storing the value.

Add:

```php
$colors[] = [ $r, $g, $b ];
```

after:

```php
$b = $rgb & 0xFF;
```

Comment: Sorry , i already edit it and still the same . Dont get the result that i want

Comment: <?php
$image = imagecreatefrompng('sobel12.png'); // imagecreatefromjpeg/png/

$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);
$colors = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
 $x_array = array() ;

 for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
  $rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
  $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
  $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
  $b = $rgb & 0xFF;

  ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); 
  $y_array = array($r, $g, $b) ;
  $x_array[] = $y_array ; 
 } 
 $colors[] = $x_array;
}
print_r($colors)
print_r(sizeof($colors));
print_r(array_sum($colors));
?>